# Tomcat trowing An invalid Lifecycle transition

Tags: java, tomcat, cas, blackboard

I just installed Blackboard 9.1 on my Ubuntu 14.04

Everything seems to work. I install the CAS authentication module. restart tomcat and everything works fine.

However, when I restart my computer... Like the next day when I come into work, Blackboard wont start.  I get this error:

```
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_start]) for component [StandardServer[8005]] in state [INITIALIZING]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:144)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
```

What is causing this error?  How do I fix this?  I assume that because this happens at a system restart, that the install process does something (set an environment var maybe?) that is not done when I start up.

I have wiped Oracle and reinstalled BB, and it works again!  but the next day... It does not start up again. :(

Any hints as to where to start would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug seems to be fixed if you're using Tomcat 7.0.20 or newer:
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51555